# Dynamic Columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I have a column `A`; I want to be able to have `A[0]` column to contain the latest value, `A[1]` to contain the most recent and so forth. Is this possible? If not is there an alternative?

Comment: You should store hashed and salted passwords, preferably using bcrypt.  It should **never** be possible to read the user's password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if MySQL can store arrays in a column. You might be better off with a `password_history` table, with this structure:

```
password_history
----------------
password
user_id
sequence_number
password_history_id
```

`password` is, well, the password! `user_id` is the ID of the user that this record's password belongs to. `sequence_number` tells you which password this is. Start with 0 for the first password, and just increase it everytime they change their password. You could also store the date that the password was created, instead of a sequence number, if you like that more. `password_history_id` is just a key column, but you could also not use this, and make the primary key a combination of the other three (and those combinations should always be unique, anyway).

Comment: This is the objective of a relational database.  If you plan to keep history of a password, then have a table for it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to model data in SQL.  Instead, you can create a PASSWORDs table, each row contains a password and the date it was replaced.  The one without a replacement date is the current one.

Of course, you should not be storing plaintext passwords in the database.

Comment: That is true.  But if they *are*, they shouldn't.  I'd bet they are, since having a history of the hashes isn't all that useful (although I guess it could be in certain circumstances).

Comment: Ever seen those login systems that tell you that your new password is not valid because you've already used it once in the past *n* months?